# How to display messages like those shown with `required="true"`

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation

The following code will display a little message balloon beside an empty text field when the submit button is clicked.

```
<form>
    <input type="text" id="name" required="true">
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

([fiddle for above](https://jsfiddle.net/cvr687mL/))

How can I trigger the display of such a balloon in `javascript`? Can I also control its message content and its display location? `jQuery` answers are OK, too.

Comment: You can just display a tooltip, but you will have to use Javascript.

Comment: You just need to decide what you want to trigger the balloon... leaving the field, a submit button, or some other event. Then create a tooltip, or animation to run when said event happens.

Comment: Downvoter, please tell me why this is a bad question, and your suggestion for improvement.

Comment: Are you using the jquery.validate library? (not downvoter)

Comment: @TravisJ, not currently, but I can if that's what's needed.

Comment: Yes, you can, i like this plugin, for example: http://www.position-relative.net/creation/formValidator/demos/demoValidators.html, but you can code it by your self, too... if you wish...

Comment: @Pratik, put your answer back up, it was helpful, if brief.

Comment: @JonathanM - It was a link only answer, and may end up being deleted if he reposts from user flags. Perhaps just having it as a comment would be more advisable.

Comment: @TravisJ, understood, but it was valuable. It should be reposted even if modified for additional content. We don't want to let our rules get in the way of getting answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This message that you see be default when you have required attribute is browsers's native behavior and the message text and location and style will change based on the browser that you use.

Chrome and FireFox will say: "Please fill out this form"
IE will say: "This is a required field"

So if you want to have a custom message you can use this JS:

```
document.getElementById('name').setCustomValidity('Your custom validation message comes here');
```

Here is the updated Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/cvr687mL/1/

And here a jquery script to trigger the validation using jquery:

```
$('input').blur(function(event) {
    event.target.checkValidity();
}).on('invalid', function(event) {
    setTimeout(function() { $(event.target).focus();}, 50);
});
```

Comment: Nice, do you maybe know is it possible to change style/appearance of error message? (If i remember well, that wasn't possible?)

Comment: @Aram, perhaps congrats were given too early. The `checkValidity()` method, checks the validity and returns true or false, but it does NOT display the message if the return value is false. Any idea how to display the message? Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cvr687mL/8/

Comment: the short answer is no. I assume you want to take advantage of HTML5 form validation without a form? I think that will not be possible (you might want to put the form tag and then the submit button but make them invisible maybe?)

Comment: @Aram, I'm ok with using a form. I would like to have the validation message appear at other times, not just when the submit button is clicked.